# TextField text Color change in searchbar

Tags: ios, colors, uisearchbar

Please check my below code, I use one `navigationbar` which is consist a `searchbar` and `searchbar` have a textfield, now i want to change a text color of `textfield` and i did a below code but it is not working so please help to correct it.

```
[[UISearchBar appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class]]]setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]]setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: Add more code work.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968907/how-to-change-uisearchbar-textfield-background-color-and-text-color-in-ios8

Comment: you can change the color of the text in the text field from storyboard itself.

Comment: search bar and navigation bar not set in storyboard. it is generated by activity view controller. so i have to configure manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a native `UISearchbar` control then you may change text color with the code below

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]}];
```

Or you can do it for a specific `searchBar` via Identity Inspector:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSArray *searchBarSubViews = [[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews];

for (UIView *view in searchBarSubViews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField *txt = (UITextField*)view;
        UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView*)textField.leftView;
        imgView.image = [imgView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        imgView.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        txt.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        txt.textColor = [UIColor RedColor];
        UIButton *btnClear = (UIButton*)[textField valueForKey:@"clearButton"];
        [btnClear setImage:[btnClear.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnClear.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```